# Chronos + Mesosphere. How to execute tasks in parallel?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesosphere

Good day everyone. 
I have single server for Chronos, Mesos and Zookeeper, and i want to use Chronos as something, what will run my scripts daily. Some scripts today, some tomorrow and so on.. 
 The problem is when i'm trying to launch tasks one after another, only first one executes correctly, another one is lost somewhere. If i launch first then take a pause of 3-4 seconds and launch another - they both are launched, but sequentially. 
 And i need to run them in parallel.
Can someone provide a hint on this? Maybe there is some settings that i must change?

Comment: **UPD: 
Thank you all for suggestions, but architecture of our application has changed and Chronos and friends became unnecessary.**

Answer (score 0):

You should set a time in UTC time for both tasks to be launched with a repeating period of 24 hours.  In this case, there is no reason why your tasks should not execute in parallel.  Check the chronos logs and the tasks logs in sandbox on mesos for errors.

Comment: When i try to run second task when first task is still running, Chronos doesn't start second task and mark it as "failure".Here is part of log :
`com.airbnb.scheduler.mesos.MesosJobFramework statusUpdate WARNING: Task with id 'ct:1412178282735:0:2' LOST Oct 01, 2014 11:44:44 AM com.airbnb.scheduler.jobs.JobScheduler handleFailedTask WARNING: Task of job: 2 failed. Oct 01, 2014 11:44:44 AM`

Comment: Can you check the log inside the slave to see where the executor of the second task is breaking?  It appears there is some issue with your second task (either requires certain resources or is somehow dependent on the other task, etc).  I haven't had a problem with running scheduled tasks in parallel.

Comment: [user4103259](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4103259/user4103259) is absolutly right! To check out if there is a problem with the configuration or with the tasks, replace the second task with some dummy one... just to see if it brakes two.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong, but it is necessary to have master and slave on separate machines, right? Now i have master and slave on single machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly run all of these components (Chronos, master, slave, and ZK) on the same machine, although ZK really becomes valuable once you have HA with multiple masters.

As user4103259 suggested, check the master and slave logs for that LOST/failed taskId to see what exactly happened to it. A task could go LOST/failed for numerous reasons, anywhere along the task launch/running/completing process.